# An oscillatory integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, oscillatory-integral

I would like to know if there is a way of expressing the integral
$$G(a) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sin(ax)\frac{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}{x} \; dx$$
in terms of known functions.

Numerically I have observed that
$$G(a) \rightarrow \frac{4}{a}$$ as $|a|\rightarrow 0$ and 
$$G(a) \rightarrow \pm \pi $$ as $a \rightarrow \pm\infty$.

Thanks.

Comment: as $x\rightarrow \infty$ the integrand behaves as $\sin(a x)$ so i have strong doubts about the convergence of ur integral (at least in the usual sense)

Comment: In a principal value sense, you have an expression in terms of Mejier G function $-\frac{1}{4} a G_{1,3}^{2,1}\left(\frac{a^2}{4}|
\begin{array}{c}
 \frac{1}{2} \\
 -1,0,-\frac{1}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Comment: Yes PV sense, thanks

Comment: you have to explain how you define a principal value. in my opinion the only way is $$ 2\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(ax) \sqrt{x^2+ 1}}{x} e^{-\epsilon x^2} dx$$

Comment: I don't agree with the PV value because the fonction to be integrated is even. I think that the integral is not convergent.

Comment: @user1952009 : $x$ is only equal to $\sqrt{x^2}$ for positive $x$, so (sadly) you can't just substract $\sin(ax)$ to the integrand to get a something convergent.

Comment: @mercio $\sin(a x) \frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x}$ is a well defined piecewise continuous function which is even. the only problem is that it doesn't tend to $0$ when $x \to \infty$. and my limit is convergent

Comment: @Frubiclé Just out of curiosity, how did you end up trying to evaluate this integral?

Comment: @Brightsun Trying to calculate the symbol of a nasty 2-dimensional singular integral operator, turned up in some thin film electrohydrodynamics stuff I was doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integral is not convergent, due to bad infrared (large $x$) behaviour, and even its Cauchy principal value 
$$
\lim_{M\to\infty}\int_{|x|<M}\frac{\sin ax}{x}\sqrt{1+x^2}dx
$$
is not well defined, since the integrand is even.

If one really wants to give a meaning to such an integral, it is possible to follow this procedure: consider the integral of the function
$$
f(z) = \frac{e^{iaz}}{z^2}\sqrt{1+z^2},\text{ for }a>0,
$$
along the contour below:

[image]

We can split the integration on the various pieces of the contour and, for $R\to\infty$, the integral on the big arcs tends to zero by Jordan's lemma, due to $a>0$. For finite $\varepsilon$, which keeps us safe from the pole at the origin, we let the contour approach the branch cut, yielding:
\begin{align}
\int_{|x|>\varepsilon}\frac{e^{iax}}{x^2}\sqrt{1+x^2}dx =& \left(e^{-i\pi/2}-e^{i\pi/2}\right)\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-ay}}{y^2}\sqrt{y^2-1}\,idy\\
&+\frac{i}{\varepsilon}\int_0^{\pi} e^{-i\varphi} d\varphi - a \int_0^{\pi}d\varphi + \mathcal O(\varepsilon)\\
=&2\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-ay}}{y^2}\sqrt{y^2-1}\, dy+\frac{2}{\varepsilon}-a\pi+\mathcal O(\varepsilon).
\end{align}
Differentiating with respect to $a$ eliminates the $a$-independent pole in $\varepsilon$, so that in the limit $\varepsilon\to0$: 
$$
PV\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{iax}}{x}\sqrt{1+x^2}dx = 2i \int_1^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-ay}}{y}\sqrt{y^2-1}\, dy +i \pi;
$$
the real part is, of course,
$$
PV\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos ax}{x}\sqrt{x^2+1}\, dx =0,
$$
whereas the imaginary part, dropping the principal value, yields
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin ax}{x}\sqrt{x^2+1}\, dx = 2 \int_1^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-ay}}{y}\sqrt{y^2-1}\,dy+\pi\equiv I(a)+\pi,
$$ 
as a consequence of the above regularisation.

Now, letting $y=\cosh\psi$,
$$
I(a) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{-a\cosh\psi}}{\cosh\psi}\sinh^2\psi d\psi 
$$
\begin{align}
I'(a) &= -\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-a\cosh\psi}\sinh^2\psi d\psi = \frac{e^{-a\cosh\psi}}{a}\sinh\psi\Big|_{-\infty}^{+\infty}-\frac{1}{a}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-a\cosh\psi}\cosh\psi d\psi\\
&= 0 + \frac{1}{a}\frac{d}{da}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-a\cosh\psi}d\psi=\frac{2}{a}K_0'(a),
\end{align}
where we have recognised the integral representation of Bessel's $K_0$ function. $K'_0(z)=-K_1(z)$, so, up to a constant $c$
$$
I(a) = 2\int_{a}^{+\infty}\frac{K_1(s)}{s}ds + c,
$$
which is convergent for $a>0$ since $K_1(z)$ decreases as $e^{-z}z^{-1/2}$ for large $z$.
The constant is zero by Lebesgue's theorem:
$$
\lim_{a\to\infty}I(a) = \int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{y^2}\lim_{a\to\infty}e^{-ay}\sqrt{y^2-1}\,dy=0
$$
since $e^{-ay}<e^{-y}$ for large $a$.

So
$${
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin ax}{x}\sqrt{x^2+1}\, dx = 2\int_{a}^{+\infty}\frac{K_1(s)}{s}ds+\pi,\text{ for }a>0.}
$$

A similar regularisation using a contour in the lower-half plane gives
$${
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin ax}{x}\sqrt{x^2+1}\, dx = -2\int_{|a|}^{+\infty}\frac{K_1(s)}{s}ds-\pi,\text{ for }a<0.}
$$

To sum up:
$$\boxed{
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin ax}{x}\sqrt{x^2+1}\, dx = \text{sign}(a)\left(2\int_{|a|}^{+\infty}\frac{K_1(s)}{s}ds+\pi\right),\text{ for }a\neq0.}
$$
This reproduces the limit $\pm\pi$ as $a\to\pm\infty$, and also the divergent behaviour $2/a$ as $a\to0,$ given by $K_1(z)\approx 1/z$ for small $z$.

Distributional meaning: consider the tempered distribution
$$
\tau(x)\equiv \frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x}\in\mathscr S'(\mathbb R),
$$
where we leave the $PV$ implicit; as such, $\tau$ has a well-defined Fourier transform given by the following action on functions $\psi\in\mathscr S(\mathbb R)$ of fast decrease
$
\langle \widehat\tau(\xi),\psi(\xi)\rangle=\langle \tau(x),\widehat\psi(x)\rangle 
$.
Now, since $1\in C^\infty$,
\begin{align}
\langle \tau(x), \widehat \psi(x)\rangle 
=& \langle x\cdot x^{-1} \tau(x), \widehat \psi(x)\rangle\\
=&\langle  x^{-1} \tau(x), x \widehat \psi(x)\rangle\\
=&-i\langle x^{-1}\tau(x), \widehat{\psi’} (x) \rangle\\
=&-i\langle \widehat{x^{-1}\tau(x)}(\xi), \psi’(\xi) \rangle\\
=&i\langle \widehat{\left(x^{-1}\tau(x)\right)}’(\xi), \psi(\xi) \rangle;
\end{align}
finally
$$
\widehat {\tau} (\xi) = i\partial_\xi \left[\widehat{x^{-1}\tau(x)}(\xi)\right]
$$
in the sense of tempered distributions.

Comment: For all of the impressive-looking analysis here, the piece where you get rid of the $1/\epsilon$ term by differentiating with respect to another parameter, while clever, is questionable.  Is it really valid to rid myself of an infinity by differentiation?  Put another way, the PV integral obviously diverges - is it valid to differentiate that?  I suppose you can define a certain type of Principal-Principal Value in which all of these steps may be taken, but then what on earth does it mean?

Comment: If one thinks of this integral as the Fourier transform of $\sqrt{1+x^2}PV(1/x)$, in the sense of tempered distributions, then differentiating with respect to $a$ is nothing but integration by parts, when the transform is smeared with a test function of fast decrease.

Comment: @Brightsun I need to check through this thoroughly at some point, thanks very much, don't have much complex analysis knowledge so this is very helpful. I have noticed numerically that the behaviour as $|a| \rightarrow 0$ does not match what I obtained so either I was wrong or I think there is an error by some constant factor somewhere.

Comment: @Frubiclé Actually, I have noticed that my expression diverges as $\pm\int_{|a|}^{1}2/s^2ds$ and not as $4/a$ for small $a$... There may be a missing pre-factor two indeed.

Comment: @Brightsun By the looks of it, I think the argument of $K_1$ should be $s/2$, but I'll check through later and see if that falls out somewhere. My limits work if I make that change

Comment: @Frubiclé I'm sorry: I'm not familiar with numerical tools. How did you make your observations on the behaviour of the integral given that the integral itself has no meaning?

Comment: @Brightsun I now completely agree with your answer, my mistake. As I had to get some sort of meaning for this integral, I was left with integrating tactically and assuming various integrals went to zero. I redid this by subtracting $\operatorname{sgn}(x)\sin(ax)$ from the integrand and then calculated this integral numerically. Then the really dirty bit was assuming that the integral of $\operatorname{sgn}(x)\sin(ax)$ is $2/a$, which is the average of $\int_{-\delta}^{\delta} \operatorname{sgn}(x)\sin(ax)$ as $\delta\to\infty$.

Comment: @Brightsun This is perhaps the dirtiest most illegal maths I have done in the last few years.

Comment: @Frubiclé Happy to hear that we agree now. As for the illegal bits of the argument, I tried to give a justification in terms of tempered distributions: maybe you can help me understand whether it is sound or not.